# ClassCastException on invoking getClass() method on object

Tags: java, avro, classcastexception

I am getting a ClassCastException when invoking getClass() method on an Avro Deserialized object. The instanceOf method on the object returns false against my class but when i upcast the object to Object class and invoke the getClass() on the Object class reference i see my class name in the output. Doesnt this mean that the object is indeed an instance of my class after all? If so, I wonder why instanceOf returns false and why getClass() causes an exception?

The application is hot-reloaded (not sure if that has something to do with it?)

Code

```
Object o = record.value();
logger.debug(" {}",o.getClass());
logger.debug(" {}",record.value() instanceof TransactionAggregate);
logger.debug(" {}",record.value().getClass());
```

Output

```
22:32:21.100 DEBUG c.m.o.f.c.consumers.Consumer:  class TransactionAggregate
22:32:21.100 DEBUG c.m.o.f.c.consumers.Consumer:  false
22:32:21.101 ERROR c.m.o.f.c.consumers.Consumer:  Consumer#2 Exception occurred: TransactionAggregate cannot be cast to TransactionAggregate
java.lang.ClassCastException: TransactionAggregate cannot be cast to TransactionAggregate
        at Consumer.run(Consumer.java:109)
        at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:40)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: what's the type of object `record`? did you try with `record.getClass()`

Comment: A class that has been loaded by two classloaders is two classes that are not equal.

Comment: user207421 - Thanks! Could you please elaborate a bit? What confuses me is that i am not doing a cast within my code but still get the ClassCastException (Not sure if getClass method is doing a cast internally). Also getClass on Object reference is succeeding! Is there any way to get the fully qualified name of the class including the classloader it was loaded with?

Comment: Mohamed Saligh - the record object is a Kafka ConsumerRecord (Key,Value).

Comment: Please post the method containing line 109 in file `Consumer.java`.